# How to make nested vertical menu with jQuery accordion?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, menu, jquery-ui-accordion

Can anyone point me to a good example on how to implement nested vertical menu using jQuery accordion? Something like [here](http://www.free-lance.ru/) (at the left of the page, starting from third item), but nested. There is no example of nested structure in Accordion docs on some reason.

Or may be there is a good jQuery component on organizing vertical nested menus I somehow missed (whatever based, not necessarily accordion)? I beleive there should be one. Can you suggest some with good initial design and preferably easily skinnable?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

i made one by myself a time ago, you could use it :
the example in the web itself : http://www.corbins.cat/
the plugin source : http://www.corbins.cat/lib/js/accordion.js

**edit** : i updated my plugin a little bit

http://gist.github.com/343543

give it a try, is nested yes, you should make html like that

```
<ul>
  <li><h4 class="trigger">title one</h4>
   <ul>
      <li><h4> class="trigger">title one.one</h4>
         <ul>
            <li> item one.one.one</li>
            <li> item one.one.two</li>
            <li> item one.one.three</li>
         </ul>
     <li>item one.two</li>
   </ul>
 <li>item two</li>
</ul>
```

let me know how it works for you! :)

Comment: Is it nested? It seems, it is limited by two levels only